# Variables in recursive .replace with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, replace, template-literals

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wev6xL8h/13/)

For a grammar correction program, I had to use 28 different `RegExp`.

So I made a simple `for` function to process all corrections together.

```
var z = $(textarea).val();
  for (const q of r){
    z = z.replace(q.x, q.y);
  }
$(textarea).val(z)
```

But in these RegExp, I have 2 redundant patterns I'd like to use as variables.

Non working example :

```
const d = new RegExp(/([^ ]+)/),
      s = new RegExp(/[·\-\.•]/),
      $e = d.source,
      $t = s.source,
      r = [
           {"x":/($e)ain$tine/gi,    "y":'$1ain $1ine'},
           {"x":/($e)oux$tsse/gi,    "y":'$1oux $1sse'},
           {"x":/($e)gnon$tagne/gi,  "y":'$1gnon $1gne'},
      ]
```

How can I do that properly ?

I found some solutions but more appliable to one `RegExp` needs.

Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much more related to javascript string interpolation. It would occur only in template strings, i.e. strings enclosed with backticks.

You then could transform your non working sample to:

```
const d = '[^ ]+', // No need to include parens twice, skipped here cause imho looks more clear to include it where it is used (below in array definition aside replacement pattern then)
  s = '[-·.•]', // Note here, reordering for '-', and skipping unneaded '\' before '.' in character class
  r = [
        {"x":new RegExp(`(${d})ain${s}ine`,'gi'),    "y":'$1ain $1ine'},
        {"x":new RegExp(`(${d})oux${s}sse`,'gi'),    "y":'$1oux $1sse'},
        {"x":new RegExp(`(${d})gnon${s}agne`,'gi'),  "y":'$1gnon $1gne'},
      ]
```

Going a little further, I think we can generalize a bit more using the following:

```
function g(male, female) {
  return new RegExp(`([^ ]+)(${male})[-·.•](${female})`, 'gi');
}

const r = [
  g('ain', 'ine'),
  g('oux', 'ouse'),
  g('gnon', 'gne')
]

$("button").on("click",function(){
  var z = $('#zone').val();
  for (const q of r){
    z = z.replace(q, '$1$2 $1$3')
  }
  $('#zone').val(z) 
});
```

- g function is our RegExp generator. RegExp reworked to capture male and female markers that will be used for replacement.
- r array constructed using the generator.
- In loop, just using `$1$2 $1$3`, meaning `{root}{male marker} {root}{female marker}`.

[Forked JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbpkm52y/)

Comment: Wow! That's so... efficient. Thanks a lot !